# Quickest way to run a REST API - using any opensource tool

Tags: php, ios

I am just creating a quick rest API to call for a iPhone application.

What is the fastest way to implement on using

- PHP
- MySQL (Data comes from database - simple user table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Zend_Rest_Server](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.rest.server.html) to wrap a simple data access object (which could use `Zend_Db`).

From Zend's Docs:

```
$server = new Zend_Rest_Server();
$server->setClass('My_Service_Class');
$server->handle();
```

Sample request:

```
?method=sayHello&who=Davey&when=Day
```

Assuming:

```
class My_Service_Class
{
    /**
    * Say Hello
    *
    * @param string $who
    * @param string $when
    * @return string
    */
    function sayHello($who, $when)
    {
        return "Hello $who, Good $when";
    }
}
```

Comment: this would require using the (shall i say bloated?) Zend Framework. Maybe this is a bit too much for our friend?

Comment: @Jacob - well, it would require using one component if it. I'm not saying he should try to implement it using Zend's MVC, Auth, ACL, (and of course the ever so simple) Form components. He asked for 'fastest way to implement' not 'smallest download and footprint'. Zend certainly can be a pick and choose framework.

Answer (score 0):

Try NuSOAP, its very simple to implement.